# ASP.Net Async file upload with Jquery/Ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I am trying to do a file upload with jQuery in an ASP.Net Web Form page.  Here is my jquery code:

```
var urlToSend = "Default.aspx/SaveNewMember"
var file = document.getElementById("MainContent_fu_image").files[0];
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append(file.name, file);    

$.ajax({                     
       type: "POST",
       url: urlToSend,               
       data:formData,
       processData: false,
       contentType: false  ,          
       success: function (response) {       
             displayMessage("success", "Added new team member");
       },
       error: function (message) {
            displayMessage("warning", 'error' + message.statusText);
       }
  });
```

and my VB code:

```
  <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()>
    Public Shared Function SaveNewMember() As String
        Dim myPage = TryCast(HttpContext.Current.Handler, _Default)
        Try
            For Each file As String In myPage.Context.Request.Files
                'do something
            Next
        Catch __unusedException1__ As Exception            
            Return ("Upload failed")
        End Try
        Return ("File uploaded successfully")
    End Function
```

The issue I am having is that when I run my code, the break point on my VB code is never hit.  Also, when I debug the jquery code, I see that the response from the server is the full HTML of the page.  What is the proper way to do an Async file upload with jQuery?

Comment: I think I see where the problem is, but not sure how to fix it.  I realized that when the user submits the form, it does not go to the specified URL (Default.aspx/SaveNewMember), which is a function on my page.  Instead, it goes to the Page_Load function.  Any ideas on why and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this wasn't the way I wanted to solve the problem, but it does work.  I would still appreciate some feedback on why I can't do this as a webmethod, in the same page.  But, I solved this problem by putting my server code in a n *.ashx file.  For those interested, here is my solution:

**jQuery:**

```
    var myFileUpload = $("#MainContent_fu_image").get(0);
    var myFiles = myFileUpload.files;
    var data = new FormData();

    data.append(myFiles[0].name, myFiles[0]);
    data.append("first_name", first_name.val());
    data.append("last_name", last_name.val());
    data.append("job_title", job_title.val());
    data.append("job_description", job_description.val());
    data.append("order_id", order_id.val());

    $.ajax({  
       url: 'FileUpload.ashx',
       type: "POST",                              
       data: data ,                
       contentType: false,
       processData: false,       
       data: data,            
       success: function (response) {     
           displayMessage("success", "Added new team member");
       },
       error: function (message) {
           displayMessage("warning", 'error' + message.statusText);
       }
   });
```

**FileUpload.ashx**

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services   

Public Class FileUpload
    Implements System.Web.IHttpHandler

    Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest

        context.Response.ContentType = “multipart/form-data”
        context.Response.Expires = -1
        Try

            Dim postedFile As HttpPostedFile = context.Request.Files.Item(0)
            Dim imgPath As String = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/FileUploads/TeamMembersPhotos/")
            Dim extension = Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName)
            Dim firstName As String = context.Request.Form.Item("first_name")
            Dim lastName As String = context.Request.Form.Item("last_name")
            Dim jobTitle As String = context.Request.Form.Item("job_title")
            Dim jobDescription As String = context.Request.Form.Item("job_description")
            Dim orderId As String = context.Request.Form.Item("order_id")
            Dim imgName As String = Convert.ToString(Guid.NewGuid()) & extension       

            If Not Directory.Exists(imgPath) Then
                Directory.CreateDirectory(imgPath)
            End If

            //function to add data to database

            If extension IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim fileLocation = String.Format(“{0}/{1}”, imgPath, imgName)
                postedFile.SaveAs(fileLocation)
                context.Response.Write(fileLocation)
                context.Response.StatusCode = 200
            End If
            context.Response.Write("{'id':'" & result & "'}")  



        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try


    End Sub

    ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```